# How to handle click listener of views in items using adapter?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `Adapter` to make a quiz activity and use multiple buttons in each item. I use `onClickListener` for tstA `ImageView`. After click, the image changes, but other tstA `ImageViews` images also change (one in every 4 items). What is the right way to do this?

[image: Picture of Activity]

Here's my code of `TestAdapter`:

```
public class TestsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TestsItem>{
    Activity holder;
    int layoutResourceId;
    TestsItem item[];

    public TestsAdapter(Context ctx, int resource, TestsItem[] testItem){
        super (ctx,resource,testItem);
        holder = (Activity)ctx;
        layoutResourceId = resource;
        item = testItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflate = holder.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflate.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
        }

        final ImageView tstA = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tstA);
        final ImageView tstB = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tstB);
        final ImageView tstC = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tstC);
        final ImageView tstD = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tstD);

        tstA.setBackgroundResource(item[position].Test1);
        tstB.setBackgroundResource(item[position].Test2);
        tstC.setBackgroundResource(item[position].Test3);
        tstD.setBackgroundResource(item[position].Test4);

        tstA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tstA.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_item_blue);
                tstB.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_item_empty);
                tstC.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_item_empty);
                tstD.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_item_empty);
            }
        });

        return  convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `item[position].Test1` `item[position].Test2` are the drawable resources that you've set as backgrounds.

So you need to modify the `onClickListener` like this.

```
tstA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        item[position].Test1 = R.drawable.test_item_blue;
        item[position].Test2 = R.drawable.test_item_empty;
        item[position].Test3 = R.drawable.test_item_empty;
        item[position].Test4 = R.drawable.test_item_empty;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

You need to change the array items you're passing in the adapter to get the proper track of your list item images. Call the `notifyDataSetChanged` to see the effect of your changes in your list.